# Android app dumps stack trace, unable to open trace file

Tags: android, eclipse

My Android app, which I'm running on a Samsung Galaxy S4 and starting via Eclipse, occasionally crashes.  Instead of dumping a stacktrace to LogCat it says that it dumps it to /data/anr/traces.txt.  The problem is I don't have permission to read the anr directory so 'adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt' just gives a permission denied error.

I just want to read my stacktrace.  Is there anyway to force it to dump to LogCat?  Or at least dump it to a file I have permission to read?

Much thanks...

Comment: that's not a crash, that's an `Application Not Responding`. It means you are blocking the ui thread somewhere with some heavy calculation or some networking operation or something.

Comment: Yeah, sorry you're right.  But I'd like to see the stacktrace to figure out where that's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to dump the logs locally like this:
adb logcat -d > log.txt

Comment: Thanks, my problem is that the stacktrace isn't being dumped to the log at all though - its being dumped to /data/anr/traces.txt, which I don't have permission to read.